# Redirect my domain to point to my Raspberry Pi server?

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, router

I've set up the Pi as a webserver and I have a domain registered with GoDaddy. I entered my public IP as an A record for the domain, and set my router to forward all traffic from the external port 80 to port 443 and my Raspberry Pi's IP.
I've got 2 questions:
1. Do I need to have the port of my RP in the domain A record so for ex. mypublicip:443 or should it just have the public IP?
2. How do I check what port is the RP using?

Answer (score 0):

The 'A' stands for 'address' and it serves as a mapping of the domain to the IP address (IPv4) of the host computer.

So your domain's A record should only contain the public IP of your server without any ports.

To access an app running over a particular port, say 8080, go to https://example.com:8080. However, you would need to set port forwarding rules in your router like you did for 80 & 443, in case you are using other ports.

To check the port, your Raspberry is listening to, run either of the following commands in the RP terminal:

- `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`
- `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`

P.S.- In case your webserver is listening on any port other than 80/443, it is recommended to set up a Caddy or Nginx server in your RP and then redirect the traffic based on url endpoint to other ports instead of exposing that port to the internet.